# Is there any way to detect the closure of android built in search box?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to detect when the built-in android search dialog is closed?  I am not using the widget but the search dialog.  I need to take a certain action at this point on my layout.  Will there be some refresh at this point where I could make my change?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it can be done using SearchManager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.OnCancelListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this about a dialog-based search or a SearchView (in an actionbar, Android 3.0+ required)?

If you are using a dialog-based search, you can create a class which extends the Dialog class, then use the OnPanelClosed() method (more about that [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onPanelClosed%28int,%20android.view.Menu%29)).

If you are using the actionbar-based searchview, you can add an OnCloseListener() listener, which will be called if the user closes the view. More on that [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnCloseListener.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the search dialog (not the widget) as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html since it is built in dialog, i'm not sure how I would substitute the build in dialog with my subclass?  Or attach a listener to the built-in one?  what do you think?

Comment: in this case you should use either the setOnDismissListener() or the setOnCancelListener(). The difference between them is that the latter only executes when the user clicks the cancel button, but the first one also executes when the search dialog is dismissed automatically at the end of a search action.